# How can i fix arc labels overlapping in d3js?

Tags: html, css, d3.js, angular5

I am drawing a doughnut chart using d3js.

I have few issues

1) the arc labels over lap over arc. Any idea how can i fix it?

[image]

2) the arc labels i am applying the style class pieChartOuterLabel , however it is not getting applied .

```
.pieChartOuterLabel {
  font-size: 1em;
  fill: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman, Times, serif';
}
```

3) How can i align the text in the center of the chart centrally aligned ?

the project is available on stack blitz.

https://angular-dbcqpg.stackblitz.io/

the code is also available at

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbcqpg

really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets answer your questions one by one.

1. To adjust the labels create a more creative function in the transform for the text like so.

```
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    let labelcoords = labelArc.centroid(d); // retrieve the label coords
    let offset = 6; // distance by which you want the labels to move out
    //now get the new label coords by running a function on them
    labelcoords[0] = adjustLabelCoords(labelcoords[0]);
    labelcoords[1] = adjustLabelCoords(labelcoords[1]);
    //This function checks if the coords are negative or positive and applies the offset
    function adjustLabelCoords(coord) {
      if (coord < 0) {
        coord = coord - offset; //if coord is negative, apply a negative offset to move more left or up
      } else if (coord > 0) {
        coord = coord + offset; //if coord is positive, apply a positive offset to move right or down
      }
      return coord;
    }
    return "translate(" + labelcoords + ")"; }
  )
```

2. The class `.pieChartOuterLabel` is being applied see the screenshot below. So I am not able to understand your issue.

[image: The css style is being applied]

You can see that the class is being applied correctly to the text.

3. Your text is already aligned in the center using the `text-anchor="middle"` attribute. I suppose you want it to be vertically also centered. To do that you can do the following:

Change your svgTextLabel to:

```
        svgTxtLabel
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("font-size", (labelSize)+'em')
          .attr("transform", `translate(0,-10)`)
          //.attr("dy", '-1.5em')
          .attr("class","pieChartCenterTextLabel")
          .transition().delay(2000)
          .text("Total");
```

and your svgTxtValue to:

```
 let svgTxtValue =   svg.append("text");
      svgTxtValue
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", (valueSize)+'em')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,10)")
        .attr("class","pieChartCenterTextLabel")
        .transition().delay(2000)
        .text(total);
```

All of this produces:

[image: Final result]

Here is the final [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ufows?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: the second issue , even the style is applied pieChartOuterLabel , however you can see that the color is grey instead of black . but great solution thank you so much

Comment: That is because the parent `g` element has a style which makes it's opacity `0.5`. If you know how to solve that then please mark the answer. If you run into trouble please leave a comment below.

Comment: i tried to set opacity to 1 but it didnt work out .pieChartOuterLabel {
  font-size: 1em;
  fill: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman, Times, serif';
  opacity: 1;
}

Comment: Its not the `.pieChartOuterLabel` that you have to change. It is the parent `g` for that which has classes like `msgdelivered`, `msgundeliverable` etc which have opacity of `0.5`. You should apply the opacity to only the sibling `path` rather than the parent `g`. Does that make sense?

Comment: i am setting opacity .5 to msgdelivered, msgundeliverable, msgenroute and msgexpired. and when i hover over those elements these are applied it should change the opacity to 1 which is expected and working fine.   I want these styles to apply only to these doughtnut arc regions , and not to the outer labels . the outer label percentages should display same style the center labels .

Comment: You should start a separate question for it as it would require significant changes then. Your original question was answered here.

Comment: sure i will start a separate question .thank you so much

Comment: i have posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871670/why-is-arc-labels-blurred-in-my-d3js-pie-chart     . appreciate if you can take a look thank you