# why is arc labels blurred in my d3js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, d3.js

I am having a piechart drawn using d3js. to the arc labels i am applying the following style.

```
.pieChartOuterLabel {
  font-size: 1em;
  fill: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman, Times, serif';
}
```

this is how my pie chart looks like. you can see the the percentage text labels are blurred ( it seems the other css styles applied to the parent elements are setting opacity to .5 to these labels).

[image]

i have tried this but it didnt work well.

```
.pieChartOuterLabel {
  font-size: 1em;
  fill: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman, Times, serif';
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

the project is available at here . what i expect the arc labels should be displayed in the same style that those in the center text of the doughnut chart.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ufows

really appreciate if you can help
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the `opacity:0.5` that you have on all your `<g>` elements, and applying the opacity on the arcs `paths` using mouse events, also I moved the tooltip a bit higher since it makes it hard to hover the arcs, here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9bhv4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)